# editing a picture with text in datagridview control from another form

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a datagridview control filled with pictures from sql db along with text writen on this pictures like names, department... On datagridview Mouse click event I would like to show a Form that has a picturebox and textbox where I could modify these info. with my code below I'm able to retrieve these info but I don't know how to save it back to the datagridview clicked cell. any idea would be appreciated

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
    Dim view As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim ht = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If (ht.ColumnIndex = 1) Then

        clickedCell = view.Rows(ht.RowIndex).Cells(ht.ColumnIndex)
        ClickedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(ht.RowIndex)
       Form2.Show()
        Form2.TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(clickedCell.ColumnIndex + 1).Value
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(clickedCell.ColumnIndex + 2).Value
        Form2.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex).Cells(clickedCell.ColumnIndex + 3).Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why cant the user edit the text right where they are in the DGV?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look on this example from Microsoft Developer Network. It shows how you create an instance of the `Form` class. In the new instance of the class you can add the picture box and text box and fetch data from your SQL database.
MSDN article: [How to: Display One Form from Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).